# Can you have a compound of a predicate nominative (noun) and predicate adjective with a single linking verb?

Tags: meaning

*Beth is a nurse.*

Nurse is the predicate nominative (noun).

*Beth is a nurse and a sailor.*

Nurse and sailor appear to me as compound predicate nominatives (nouns).

*Beth is funny.*

Funny is the predicate adjective.

*Beth is funny and clever.*

*Funny* and *clever* are the compound predicate adjectives.

*Beth is a nurse and funny.*

Can *nurse* and *funny* be considered a compound of predicate nominative and predicate adjective? Is the sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: The sentence is entirely grammatical (see *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston, Pullum, et al. (2002), p.1323 and onwards, and particularly pp.1326–27) and semantically anomalous (infelicitous) due to [a slight difference in meaning of *be*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/166440/you-cant-be-nice-and-be-a-rock-star-at-the-same-time#comment332481_166440) between *Beth is a nurse* (= "belongs to the class of nurses") and *Beth is funny* (= "has the quality of being funny").

Comment: @userr2684291 Grammatically correct but infelicitous. Good. But if the sentence is extended to "Beth is a nurse, funny and clever," is it still correct if infelicitous?

Comment: Yes, that sentence is again grammatical. As CGEL puts it, "There is no grammatical limit to the number of coordinates that can be joined in a single layer of coordination." (provided they are valid coordinates: syntactically alike (which they are) and satisfying all the little sub-conditions (which they do)).

Comment: You're confusing nouns and noun phrases (which are often confused by those trained in traditional grammar).  In "Beth is a nurse", "a nurse" is a predicate nominative noun phrase, but "nurse" is merely a noun, which is just a word, not a noun phrase.  The noun phrase "a nurse" is made up of the article "a" and the noun "nurse".

Comment: @userr2684291  In the sentence "Beth is a nurse, funny and clever," how would you determine that funny and clever are coordinates and not appositives? If funny and clever are appositives, that would read to me as all nurses are funny and clever, not just Beth.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely correct, but the confusion that arises from it is probably because it's an instance of [syllepsis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/S/syllepsis.htm) - the verb can be taken differently in regards to each of *doctor* and *funny*. Also, because constructions like this are not particularly common, readers are somewhat conditioned to expect noun-&-noun or adjective-&-adjective.

There is nothing wrong with *Beth is a doctor and funny*, but if you want to avoid the feeling of discomfort you get from the mashup, just put in a comma or hyphen: *Beth is a doctor, and funny*/*Beth is a doctor - and funny*.

Answer (score -2):

Ultimately, the sentence 
***Beth is a doctor and funny*** doesn't make any sense.  So you might want to rethink the entire sentence construction.

The sentence ***Beth is a nurse and funny***, however, may be grammatically unique due to a particular semantical construction in which it has a significance, as the  grammatical construction is otherwise unfit using other words, with the same functions.