# “Everyone is fine and having fun” or “Everyone is fine and is having fun.”

Tags: word-usage, writing-style, ellipses, parallelism

While both sentences are probably grammatical, I’m wondering which one is preferable. To me, the first sentence sounds awkward, but the second sentence may have an unnecessary *is*. Basing your answers on grammar (or a style rule), which sentence should be used, or better yet, which sentence is preferable over the other? Is the second *is* in the second sentence necessary, and if it is, what does it do to improve the sentence?

PS: Based on parallel structure, I personally believe that the second sentence is more correct.

Comment: Of course the first one is always preferable.

Comment: I didn't DV you, but it seems like some people believe this is primarily opinion-based  [POB] and are voting to close. Possible they also expect more research to be shown...

Comment: @Cascabel “Research”? What type of research? It’s a question of parallel structure.

Comment: Neither is more "correct". Use the one you prefer.

Comment: Related: [Can you have a compound of a predicate nominative (noun) and predicate adjective with a single linking verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/456903/26083)  (although that one got up voted).

Comment: @Scott That’s funny. Truly, Scott, you should do stand-up.

Comment: I have little idea as to why this post garnered four downvotes.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say both are correct and that the second one is a case of ellipsis. But I'm not sure exactly which it is. Here is a list of examples from Wikipedia about different types of ellipsis.

> Gapping
>  "John can play the guitar, and Mary (can play) the
>   violin."
>
> Pseudogapping
>  They have been eating the apples more than (they
>   have been eating) the oranges.
>
> Stripping
>  Sam has attempted problem 1 twice, and (he has
>   attempted) problem 2 also.
>
> Verb phrase ellipsis
>  John can play the guitar; Mary (can play the
>   guitar), too.
>  [Ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)#Sluicing)

The ellipsis is the part of the sentences in brackets that can be left out to avoid repetition because they're understood from their previous use. In your case what is elided or omitted is the verb "to be".

I suppose it's a lot like saying "I am smart and funny" instead of "I am smart and I am funny."

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, none of it is more preferable. More toward a preference if i may say because it is unheard of that it is better than the other for such context.

The conjunction ‘and’ is a coordinating conjunction. It is under the copulative or cumulative conjunction which merely to connect or link two clauses that are grammatical of equivalent value.

Everyone is fine. Everyone is having fun.

Everyone is fine and having fun.

Answer (score 0):

Why would No.1 sound awkward to you?

> 1. “Everyone **is** fine and having fun”

The second sentence is

> 2. “Everyone **is** fine and **is** having fun.”

Compare:

> "I **am** fine and having fun"
>   "We **are** fine and having fun"

with

> "I **am** fine and **am** having fun"  (very awkward)
>   "We **are** fine and **are** having fun" (less awkward)

Furthermore, I'd suggest that in informal speech it's quite common to hear the following

> 3. “Everyone **is** fine and ***we're/they're*** all having fun.”